# ¿Tiene algún error más?

Tags: python, sql, json

Este código me falla en la 2 línea porque dice no existe el fichero y no lo puede abrir, el caso es que está bien escrito y en el mismo directorio, como puedo solucionarlo y de paso si hay más errores os lo agradecería.

```
**import json
with open('./data.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

tabla = 'Datos'

sql_query = f"INSERT INTO {tabla} "

columnas = []
for key in data[0].keys():
   columnas.append(key)

columnas_str = f"({', '.join(columnas)})"

valores = []
for row in data:
row_values = []
for value in row.values():
    if isinstance(value, str):
        row_values.append(f"'{value}'")
    else:
        row_values.append(str(value))
valores.append(f"({', '.join(row_values)})")

valores_str = ', '.join(valores)

sql_query += f"{columnas_str} VALUES {valores_str};"

print(sql_query)**
```

---

[image: Aquí está @sandiooo]

Este es el árbol de ficheros, @sandiooo

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask]. Céntrate en solo _un problema_, ya que este sitio no es un servicio de depuración de código ni de "encuentre el error". Pon en el título el problema _específico_ que estés teniendo.

Comment: El error es claro, nunca te va a engañar, mejor revisa bien. Y hay otros errores muy graves (de seguridad). Y no te olvides de hacer caso a las recomendaciones que te dieron :D.

Comment: Si te dice que no existe el _fichero_ y tú dices que si existe, el problema va a estar en la ruta actual de la ejecución, que no es la que tu crees. Quizás sea mejor que utilices una ruta absoluta y no una ruta relativa. Es decir, mejor "/user/juan/home/data.json" o "C:\\users\\juan\\documentos\\data.json" y no la ruta relativa (la que comienza con "./", pues esa ruta es relativa a la ruta actual de la ejecución , que no necesariamente es la ruta donde está el script.

Comment: @padaleiana vale si tienes razón, lo siento. Ya se que hay de seguridad pero es un código rápido que solo lo voy a utilizar yo solo, lo he intentado con rutas relativas y absolutas y al ejecutar el interprete de python sigue sin abrir el archivo. Con la última opción así también lo he probado y nada no me funciona con with open( 'data.json', 'r' ) as file:.

Comment: Asegúrate de que estás ejecutando el script `jsontosql.py` desde el subdirectorio `db_files`. Que tu script se encuentre en dicha carpeta no implica que el directorio actual (esto es, "." al usar la ruta relativa) sea ese.

Comment: Si el Json está en la misma carpeta del Py, creo saber cual es el problema, revisa los permisos del directorio y del archivo.

Comment: No se no se me abre ns el porq si está bien colocado y tiene los permisos y todo, total q hice también un simple servidor web y la página web q estaba en el mismo directorio tampoco la abría.

Answer (score 0):

no soy un experto en python, pero para empezar hay un error en los for. creo que el segundo for debe estar dentro del primero segun mi poca experiencia, el codigo resuelto se veria asi:

```
import json

with open('./data.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

tabla = 'Datos'

sql_query = f"INSERT INTO {tabla} "

columnas = []
for key in data[0].keys():
    columnas.append(key)

columnas_str = f"({', '.join(columnas)})"

valores = []
for row in data:
    row_values = []
    for value in row.values():
        if isinstance(value, str):
            row_values.append(f"'{value}'")
        else:
            row_values.append(str(value))
    valores.append(f"({', '.join(row_values)})")

valores_str = ', '.join(valores)

sql_query += f"{columnas_str} VALUES {valores_str};"

print(sql_query)
```

Con respecto a lo del archivo json, el error es bastante claro, debes asegurarte de que estas llamando o invocando al json desde y hacia el lugar correcto, recuerda que cada punto **'.'** es un nivel subido, si el json esta en otra carpeta deberia ser "../data.json", y si dentro de esa carpeta hay otra carpeta crece el nivel de puntos "../../../data.json", como el tuyo tiene un solo punto, deberia el json estar dentro de la misma carpeta que este documento que mostraste. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Vale perfecto lo probaré así, con respecto el JSON lo he probado de mil maneras, con rutas relativas y absolutas lo he movido de una carpeta a otra y nada, nunca me lo lee.

Comment: podrias subir una captura de tu arbol de archivos, me gustaria ver a mejor detalle donde esta el json